# Cannot return object

Tags: c#, odata, odata-v4

I want to return this object by finding it by it's name:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
}
```

The controller method is:

```
[HttpGet]
[ODataRoute("Products/ProductService.GetByName(Name={name})")]
public IHttpActionResult GetByName([FromODataUri]string name)
{
    Product product = _db.Products.Where(x => x.Name.Equals(name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).SingleOrDefault();
    if (product == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return Ok(product);
}
```

And the `WebApiConfig.Register()` method is:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
    builder.EntitySet<Product>("Products");

    builder.Namespace = "ProductService";
    builder.EntityType<Product>().Collection.Function("GetByName").Returns<Product>().Parameter<string>("Name");

    config.MapODataServiceRoute(routeName: "ODataRoute", routePrefix: null, model: builder.GetEdmModel());
}
```

By calling `http://http://localhost:52542/Products(1)` I do get the product with the ID 1 as expected:

```
{
 "@odata.context":"http://localhost:52542/$metadata#Products/$entity","Id":1,"Name":"Yo-yo","Price":4.95,"Category":"Toy"
}
```

But when I'm calling `http://http://localhost:52542/Products/ProductService.GetByName(Name='yo-yo')` I do can debug into the controller function and the result is being returned but I get an error in the browser saying that `An error has occurred.`. The message is `The 'ObjectContent 1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/json; odata.metadata=minimal'.` and the inner exception is `The related entity set or singleton cannot be found from the OData path. The related entity set or singleton is required to serialize the payload.`.

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your function configuration has some problem.
You should call as follows to define the return:

```
builder.EntityType<Product>().Collection.Function("GetByName").ReturnsFromEntitySet<Product>("Products").Parameter<string>("Name");
```

Then it can work. Thanks.

Comment: So that worked! Thx a lot. I now see the difference between my code and your code.

Comment: I'm finding that learning how to use `ODataConventionModelBuilder` properly is no small task. Not feeling the productivity so much